# Linq и Active Record

Tags: c#, orm, linq

Попытка использовать ORM, реализующий паттерн "репозиторий" непосредственно в качестве модели для UI - это адская смесь с непредсказуемыми побочными эффектами из-за невнятной модели времени жизни подключения.

Есть у меня в БД две связанные таблицы. Linq2Sql генерирует для них два класса со свойствами, представляющими связанный объект / список связанных объектов. Если сохранение объектов осуществляется только через контекст, который можно взять в using, то получение данных может производиться как через контекст, так и через эти свойства. Сигнатура которых совершенно не проверяет наличие контекста.

В результате невозможно гарантированно отследить ситуацию, когда я обращаюсь к этим свойствам в тот момент, когда контекст уже уничтожен, и получаю внезапные исключения и прочие глюки. И вынужден делать костыли, чтобы это обходить.

Я уже не говорю о том, с какой скоростью выполняется метод SubmitChanges, не предоставляющий возможности оповещать пользователя о прогрессе операции.

При использовании паттерна Active Record подключение к БД всегда глобально доступно, и подобных проблем не возникает. Наличие класса TransactionScope позволяет безболезненно работать с этим подключением в транзакциях.

Ну не могли Microsoft, если так не любят Active Record, хотя бы вместо свойств сделать методы, принимающие в качестве параметра экземпляр контекста?

Понятно, что в моём ядре документооборота с этим порядок, но, во-первых, проект, в котором я сталкиваюсь со всеми этими проблемами, уже давно делается на Linq2Sql, во-вторых, в своём ядре я не смог сделать достаточную для этого проекта поддержку Linq.

Comment: >Попытка использовать ORM, реализующий паттерн "репозиторий" непосредственно в качестве модели для UI 

you are not sane, you are insane!

Comment: Между прочим, именно это Microsoft предлагают в QuickStart по ASP.NET MVC Framework.

Comment: интересно посмотреть пруф

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-%28data%29
Там, правда, EF, но разница небольшая.

Comment: для меня понятие "репозиторий" - это класс предоставляющий удобный API для получения, добавления, обновления и удаления данных, в вашем примере описывается тоже самое, а UI уже строится на основе модели, с которой работает репозиторий или я что недопонимаю?

Comment: Моя претензия к Microsoft в том, что т.н. navigation properties выглядят так, как будто не зависят от наличия контекста, но на самом деле зависят. Мало того, никаких ссылок на контекст DTO не имеют.